# Baby Rudin 2.17 Perfect Set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I'm confused about the solution to 2.17 in Baby Rudin. Let  be the set of all ∈[0,1] whose decimal expansion contains only the digits 4 and 7. Is  countable? Is  dense in [0,1]? Is  compact? Is  perfect?

The solution says that E is perfect. However, I don't see how E has a single limit point. For example, take .7 and let $\epsilon$ = .03 . Any other point q in E must be $\geq$ .74 or $\leq$ .48.    .74 - .7 = .04 $\geq$ .03, and .7 - .48 = .22 $\geq$ .03. So $N_.03(.7)$ contains only .7 in E, so .7 is not a limit point.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $0.7$ isn’t in $E$ in the first place.

Comment: Is the decimal expansion of $.7$ just $.7$ or $.70000\dots$? If the latter, it’s not in $E$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number $0.7$ does *not* belong to $E$, since $0.7=0.70000\ldots$. Elements of $W$ are, for instance $0.77777\ldots$, $0.7474474447\ldots$ and so on.

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you!